# Only get pointermove event from OpenLayers when mouse button is pressed

Tags: openlayers, angular, typescript, mouse-position

I'm trying to get hover position with 'pointermove' event from OpenLayers Map.

```
    const source = new OlXYZ({
        url: 'https://tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
    });

    this.layer = new OlTileLayer({
        source: source
    });

    this.view = new OlView({
        center: fromLonLat([6.661594, 50.433237]),
        zoom: 2
    });

    this.map = new OlMap({
        target: this.mapId,
        layers: [this.layer],
        view: this.view
    });

    this.vectorSource = new VectorSource({
        features: []
    });
    this.vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
        source: this.vectorSource
    });
    this.map.addLayer(this.vectorLayer);

    this.map.on('pointermove', (e) => {
        console.log("Map hovered")
    });

    this.map.on('click', (e) => {
        console.log("Map clicked")
    });
```

But the *pointermove* event only fires while left mouse button is clicked and hold when moving the cursor. Like a "drag event". The event should fire by just hovering over map.

The *click* event never fires (for anything).

Anyone familiar with this problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Does your device need pointer event polyfills? https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/tag/v6.4.0

Comment: No I don't think so. I use the latest version of Chrome (v.94)

Comment: I use v6.5.0 of OpenLayers.